# How to read parameters from parameters.yml in a service?

Tags: symfony

I have created a service where I need to read few parameters from parameters.yml, so far I am able to read parameters through container only,  *I have injected container into my service*, I know it's not good practice to inject container instead I should be injecting required services/components,however I am not able to figure out the way to read parameters from parameters.yml without injecting container into service and then reading parameters with the help of container.
Can you please guide me for an alternative solution?

**EDIT:**

I have a long list of parameters, around 12-15, I am storing rate limit options for API in parameters.yml so that they can be easily configured

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a long list a parameters injecting these one by one would be harsh but you can inject array of parameters.

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    array_name:
        param1: value1
        param2: value2
        ...
```

services.yml

```
services:
    your_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Class
        arguments: [%array_name%]
```

your service:

```
public function __construct(array $parameters)
{
    //access $parameters['param1'], $parameters['param2']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass it in the definition of the service. As example in this xml definition:

```
    <service id="amce.example_service" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Example">
        <argument type="service" id="templating" />
        <argument>%my_from_parameters%</argument>
    </service>
```

Hope this help

Comment: I can do that however I have a long list of parameters, around 12-15, I am storing rate limit options for API  in  parameters.yml so that they can be easily configured, the list can go on increasing

Comment: Include all your parameters in an array configuration and pass it to the service in the same manner. I can post you an example not before six hours, let me know if you need it

Comment: thanks @Matteo for your reply Tomasz posted an example in his answer

Comment: Is exactly what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter into your service actually. Like this:

```
service_name:
    class: <pathToClass>
    arguments:
        - %<parameter-name>%
```